# Raising errors: Ugly code... Better way to write?

Tags: python, code-readability

```py
def positive_int(value):
    try:
        ivalue = int(value)
    except:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%s is an invalid positive int value" % value)
    if ivalue <= 0:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%s is an invalid positive int value" % value)
    return ivalue
```

Just think that the code above is brutally ugly. The first part is error-inducing and the other is a check if the value is satisfiable. Error should be raised if at least one of them fails. Is there a way to string these to checks together, so that I don't need to repeat lines? Or just a better and prettier alternative in general? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You could change the code in the `except` block to be `ivalue = -1`, that way you only have to write the error text once ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will raise a generic Exception if the value is negative inside the `try:` block, causing it to re-raise the same exception as it would if `int(value)` threw an exception

```
def positive_int(value):
    try:
        ivalue = int(value)
        if ivalue <= 0:
            raise Exception
    except:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%s is an invalid positive int value" % value)

    return ivalue
```